# Grabbing a series of frames from an RTSP stream

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm looking for a way to continuously grab frames, as jpg, from a RTSP stream. I've stumbled upon ffmpeg but it seems that the time between starting it and grabbing the first frame is quite high. Is there any good tool in order to do this?

Regards

Comment: take a look at [live555](http://www.live555.com) project

Answer (score 0):

I've used [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) libraries in the past to extract frames from mobile video